# Can we normalize a relation directly to 3NF without normalizing to 2NF first?

Tags: database-normalization

I have an homework which should be submitted tomorrow
I normaly know normalization concepts but in some questions I have difficulty. 
How should i normalize this to BCNF? Can you show the steps please?

```
R(A,B,C,D,E,F,H)
```

FD set are

```
A->D
AE->H
DF->BC
E->C
H->E
```

for this realtion I have to find the keys and normalize to BCNF..
 If I normalize to 2NF I loose some relations which doesn't suit to 3NF. So I am confused.
Any help will be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: What happened to "G"? Typo? (It's pretty unusual for homework examples to use a set of letters that *isn't* contiguous.) Also, what keys did you identify, and how did you proceed from there?

Comment: Hello,I checked again there is no G. Candidate keys are not given but it is also part of question. I found 2 candidate keys which are A,F,E and A,F,H . Do you think is it true ? Thank you for your help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic requirements for a database to be in third normal form:

- **Already meet the requirements of both 1NF and 2NF**
- Remove columns that are not fully dependent upon the primary key.

If you normalize in 2NF you wont lose any relations, rather you will get another relation.
Okay so lets do your homework now.

Lets start by assuming that your relations are already in 1NF.
Now for 2NF

```
R1 = AE -> {H}(AE->H)
R2 = DF -> {B, C}(DF->BC)
R3 = A  -> {D}(A->D)
R4 = E -> {C}(E->C)
```

The above relation is in 2NF, none of the non-prime attributes are partially dependent on the candidate key. And also in 3NF because there is not transitive relationship within a relation.

okay now for BCNF, all the relation obey BCNF except for R1 because H->E relationship holds in R1 and H does not belong to the candidate key in R1.

Beeri and Bernstein showed in 1979 that, for example, a set of functional dependencies {AB → C, C → B} cannot be represented by a BCNF schema by preserving the dependencies that held in the original table. Read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form#Achievability_of_BCNF) for further details.

But you can still convert it into BCNF,

```
R1 = A -> {E}
R2 = E -> {H}
R3 = DF -> {B, C}
R4 = A  -> {D}
R5 = E -> {C}
```

But the above tables dose not hold the original relationship AE-> H, making it inconsistent and this relationship being BCNF non-achievable by preserving the dependencies that held in the original table.

Comment: Hello,I asked my question in a wrong way possibly. I know that there may be some relations which may already hold the 1NF and 2NF conditions but according to my candidate key findings (which may be wrong) this does not hold 2NF. So in this condition first I have to normalize this to 2NF and than 3NF. I didn't understand your solution (possibly my candidate key AFE or AFE is different than yours). What was your candidate key? Thank you for  your help and interest

Comment: Okay, Now for a relation **R** there exists a candidate key, but that candidate is in-significant because it will not be 2NF or 3NF as you pointed out.

Comment: To normalize to 2NF you should know the candidate key isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right any candidate key will fail to obey 2NF. I realized that I mistyped above. My candidate keys are AFE or AFH is this wrong ? (From D and F I can reach B)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21190/discussion-between-chipmunk-and-ferda-ozdemir)

Comment: I had to go to sleep last night. I didn't see your invitation. I had to study more I didn't understand your this approval my candidate keys really. Today I will think with a clear mind hopefully and deliver the homework.

Comment: @Chipmunk:  You said, "AFE or AFH will fail to identify B in the row." You're mistaken. You might want to compute the closure of both those again.

Comment: @Catcall I apologize, I totally ignored "F" from the picture.

Comment: @Chipmunk: You should edit or delete your comment. Also, we [don't tag homework any more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, but not your description of it, yes, you can normalize from 1NF to 3NF without *stopping* at 2NF in the process.

A common misconception is that you can start with relation(s) in 1NF and

- normalize them to 2NF *and no higher*, then
- normalize them to 3NF *and no higher*, then
- normalize them to BCNF *and no higher*.

It's common, but it's still a misconception. You can see counterexamples to this misconception in any number of textbooks, but you have to look closely at their examples. As far as I know, no textbook *explicitly identifies* this misconception, but it becomes obvious if you study their examples.

In practice, it's common to go from 1NF or 2NF to 5NF or 6NF in a single step. For example, going from 2NF to 5NF just means that you remove a transitive dependency, and

- you find no remaining dependencies in which the left-hand side is *not* a candidate key (required for BCNF),
- you find no remaining multi-value dependencies (required for 4NF), and
- you find no remaining join dependencies (required for 5NF).

This happens a *lot* in examples on StackOverflow. (2NF to 5NF or 6NF, that is.)

---

In homework problems expressed in the notation you used, you're expected to assume the starting relation is in 1NF. Your first job is to identify the keys. Why? Because you can't normalize to 2NF unless you can identify partial-key dependencies, and you can't do *that* unless you know all the candidate keys.

You are correct in identifying the keys as AEF and AFH. Since one of the dependencies is A->D, relation R is not in 2NF. D depends only on A, and A is *part* of a candidate key. To normalize to 2NF, identify all the partial-key dependencies, and eliminate them by projection.

Start with this.

- R(ABCDEFH), keys {**AEF, AFH**}

Remove the partial-key dependency A->D.

- R<sub>1</sub>(ABCEFH), keys {**AEF, AFH**}
- R<sub>2</sub>(**A** D)

R<sub>2</sub> is in 6NF.

Removing that partial-key dependency from R results in R<sub>1</sub>. The functional dependency DF->BC doesn't apply to R<sub>1</sub>, because R<sub>1</sub> doesn't contain attribute D.  But DF->BC still *does* apply to the overall design.  This is the point that was confusing you.

Most of the time, functional dependencies end up being simple key constraints. That's what happened when the FD A->D became R<sub>2</sub>. But since projection split the left-hand side of DF->BC, *that* dependency has to be expressed in a different way--as a database constraint. (SQL isn't good at that. CREATE ASSERTION is supposed to cover those bases, but nobody's implemented it yet.)

Comment: I agree, but there is no real use of skipping 2NF in real-world, 5NF and further is okay but the first 3 are essential

Comment: Whether you *skip* 2NF isn't up to you. It's entirely dependent on the relation's functional dependencies. Starting in 1NF, it might be *impossible* to reach 2NF *and no higher*. Of course any normal form  higher than 2NF is automatically *also* in 2NF, but that's not the point.

Comment: You understand very well why I was confused. Your answer is true Thank you. The other answer is also true.. I can not choose 2 answer as true in the same time. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this.

R(ABCDEFH), keys {AEF, AFH}
Remove the partial-key dependencies A->D and E->C.

R1(ABEFH), keys {AEF, AFH}
R2(**A** D)
R3(**E** C)

R1,R2 and R3 are in 2NF.

Removing that partial-key dependency from R results in R1. The functional dependency DF->BC doesn't apply to R1, because R1 doesn't contain attribute D. But DF->BC still does apply to the overall design. This is the point that was confusing you.

Here, I continue the comments of Mike.

You have to note that even if R1 doesn't contain attribute D, R1 contains A. As AF->DF->BC, the dependency DF->BC still holds in R1.

for the 3NF, we need to remove transitive dependencies DF->B and DF->C, and we get:

R1(AEFH), keys {AEF, AFH}
R2(**A** D)
R3(**E** C)
R4(**D F** B C)

all relations are in 3NF.